# Paypal API Bad request passing more than one item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I'm developing an app that has paypal transactions. I'm using the `'paypal-sdk-rest'` gem to make the connection to the paypal api but I'm having troubles trying to pass more than one item to the cart.

Let's see this example to specify what I'm talking about.

This works:

```
 payment = {
      :intent => "sale",
      :payer => {:payment_method => "paypal"},
      :transactions => 
        [{
          :amount => {
            :total => '500',
            :currency => "USD" },
          :item_list => {
            :items => { :name => "pizza", :sku => "pizza", :price => '500', :currency => "USD", :quantity => 1 },
          },
          :description => "Some description"
        }],
      :redirect_urls => {
        :return_url => "http://localhost:3000/somepath",
        :cancel_url => "http://localhost:3000/otherpath"
      }
    }

    @payment = Payment.new(payment)
    @payment.create
```

But this doesn't (added one item to the items list):

```
 payment = {
      :intent => "sale",
      :payer => {:payment_method => "paypal"},
      :transactions => 
        [{
          :amount => {
            :total => '500',
            :currency => "USD" },
          :item_list => {
            :items => [{ :name => "pizza", :sku => "pizza", :price => '500', :currency => "USD", :quantity => 1 },{ :name => "pizza2", :sku => "pizza2", :price => '1000', :currency => "USD", :quantity => 1 }],
          },
          :description => "Some description"
        }],
      :redirect_urls => {
        :return_url => "http://localhost:3000/somepath",
        :cancel_url => "http://localhost:3000/otherpath"
      }
    }

    @payment = Payment.new(payment)
    @payment.create
```

The thing is I want something similar to the second one, as I want to add many items to the transaction, in fact, every item that is in my cart. Is my problem clear?

Any help would be VERY appreciated as I've been trying to solve this for like one entire day and tried everything but had no luck.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?  "doesn't work" isn't going to help us troubleshoot.

Comment: As I've said in the question title, I get a "bad request (status 400)" when posting to the paypal payment, just adding another item to the purchase. I guess cause the json is not well-formed. What am I making wrong? How to make a purchase of two items with the paypal api may be a similar question if what i'm doing is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, finally! The thing was that the total from amount had to be concordant to the total price of the items added. So in that example, the error was that `:total` had to be `'1500'` instead of `'500'`, as the total of both item prices was `1500`.